# MOSFET problems!

Tags: heated-bed, diy-3d-printer

I ordered a MOSFET module on eBay for my 3D printer and I did not get the one in the picture but I got this:

[image: The thing I received]

If there is any way I could use this on my Anet A8 could someone tell me how, as it only has one input connector, DC in, and 12 V out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, this module is completely useless for your intended purpose.

The load side is marked with "5A 5-220VDC". This means it can only switch up to 5A, maximum. The heated bed draws more than twice this current.